# swipe toolbar to in browserandroid

Tags: android, toolbar, swipe

Hey i'am working on a browser app for android.

know i wan't to make a toolbar that shows when swiping up like the pictures on these links

[Before swiping](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4xg9f1h4wx6a96/Screenshot_2013-02-15-13-47-41.png)

[After swiping](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jcljkvk6czs1l6/Screenshot_2013-02-15-13-48-06%20%281%29.png)

My question is how does i get the toolbar to work with swipe.

I write the codes in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

See this example project. [android miscwidgets](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/) I think this is what you want. Just set the panel:position="bottom" in XML and here it is.

Comment: So can you elaborate in detail what you want to do?

Comment: like i say before. i want to make a toolbar (LinearLayout) in my layout.xml scroolable so man can hide the toolbar with just scrool the toolbar down